# Laptop does not work without power source

Tags: power-management, freeze, manjaro

Installed manjaro linux to the laptop today and discovered that it is not working with disconnected power source.

Here is `dmesg` output:
[image]

And `upower -d`:
[image]

Manjaro 15.9, kernel 4.1.8, Cinnamon DE (if it is necessary).
Symptoms are: 1 second of music is playing in the infinite loop, no reaction for mouse or keyboard.
I've found that the bug affect not only me, but for others this message don't cause PC freeze.

Comment: Do you have an actual question?  this is a bug report.

Comment: Well, my question is "what can i do", because i don't know :D

Comment: Replace battery, because it reports 100%, and behaves 0%. Try shutdown, remove & inspect battery, reinsert.